# Creating Resource Mail box on O365 using API (Graph)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, o365-flow

Has anyone ever created resource mailbox on O365 using graph API or any other API.

Any advise be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: If you want to create mailboxes/resource mailboxes, then you need to consider using Powershell or Exchange Admin Console (EAC). AFAIK, i never heard that you can do with MS Graph API!!

Comment: Are you still looking for help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create mailboxes/resource mailboxes, then you need to consider using Powershell or Exchange Admin Console (EAC). AFAIK, i never heard that you can do with MS Graph API!!